# Android Firebase deeplinking after installation from Google Play

Tags: android, firebase, google-play

I am switching deeplinks implementation from [Yozio](http://www.yozio.com/) to [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/). Yozio allowed me to get deeplink data when the application was installed and launched from Google Play. Yozio is using INSTALL_REFFERER broadcast and campaign data which are sent within the broadcast. Is it possible with Firebase?

Comment: So far the only remotly related thing I found is Firebase Dynamic Links https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/android#set-up-firebase-and-the-dynamic-links-sdk. Other then that - nothing. Maybe it's possible to write a custom BroadcastReceiver and send data to Firebase manually?